# Explode indexed array data horizontal

Tags: php, file, explode, php-7.4

After having imported the data I would like to explode the data of each sub-array horizontal, with space as delimiter. The part of each lines might differ in amounts.

**My data:**

```
#ORGNR   "123" 1
#ACCOUNT    1010    "Kassa"
#ACCOUNT    1050    "Bank"
#IB     -1 1010        1923.15
#IB     1 1050         201.42
```

**My script:**

```
$array = file('data.txt');
print_r($array);
```

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => #ORGNR   "123" 1

    [1] => #ACCOUNT 1010    "Kassa"

    [2] => #ACCOUNT 1050    "Bank"

    [3] => #IB     -1 1010        1923.15

    [4] => #IB     1 1050         201.42

)
```

**Wanted result (just showing the first line)**

```
Array
(
    [0] => [0 => #ORGNR, 1 => "123",2 => 1]
    // Line 2
    // Line 3
    // Line 4
    // Line 5

)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best method is to preg_split instead of explode since it will take care of extra spaces.

```
$str = '#ORGNR   "123" 1
#ACCOUNT    1010    "Kassa"
#ACCOUNT    1050    "Bank"
#IB     -1 1010        1923.15
#IB     1 1050         201.42';

$arr = explode("\n", $str); // you use file but it's the same thing

foreach($arr as &$val){
    $val = preg_split("/\s+/", $val);
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Output of above:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "#ORGNR"
    [1]=>
    string(5) ""123""
    [2]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "#ACCOUNT"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "1010"
    [2]=>
    string(7) ""Kassa""
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "#ACCOUNT"
    [1]=>
    string(4) "1050"
    [2]=>
    string(6) ""Bank""
  }
  [3]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "#IB"
    [1]=>
    string(2) "-1"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "1010"
    [3]=>
    string(7) "1923.15"
  }
  [4]=>
  &array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(3) "#IB"
    [1]=>
    string(1) "1"
    [2]=>
    string(4) "1050"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "201.42"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/9hPVd

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = '#ORGNR   "123" 1
#ACCOUNT    1010    "Kassa"
#ACCOUNT    1050    "Bank"
#IB     -1 1010        1923.15
#IB     1 1050         201.42';

$result = explode(PHP_EOL, $string);
foreach ($result as $k => $v) {
    $result[$k] = preg_split('/\s+/', trim($v));
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

or

```
$string = '#ORGNR   "123" 1
#ACCOUNT    1010    "Kassa"
#ACCOUNT    1050    "Bank"
#IB     -1 1010        1923.15
#IB     1 1050         201.42';
echo($string);
$result = explode(PHP_EOL, $string);
foreach ($result as $k => $v) {
    $result[$k] = explode(' ', trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $v)));
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

result

```
[
    [0] => 'Array',
    [
        [0] => '#ORGNR',
        [1] => '"123"',
        [2] => '1',
    ]

    [1] => 'Array',
    [
        [0] => '#ACCOUNT',
        [1] => '1010',
        [2] => '"Kassa"',
    ]

    [2] => 'Array',
    [
        [0] => '#ACCOUNT',
        [1] => '1050',
        [2] => '"Bank"',
    ]

    [3] => 'Array',
    [
        [0] => '#IB',
        [1] => '-1',
        [2] => '1010',
        [3] => '1923.15',
    ]

    [4] => 'Array',
    [
        [0] => '#IB',
        [1] => '1',
        [2] => '1050',
        [3] => '201.42',
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, this is what you want to do.

```
$dataAsArray = file('data.txt');
$result = [];
foreach ($dataAsArray as $data) {
    $result[] = explode(' ', $data);
}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: The answer does the basics correct and solve the question. I forgot to mention in the question that some content will have blanks but grouped by double quotes and I suspect that the spaces in between might be tabs.

Comment: I do not understand how this is correct.. https://3v4l.org/H9cTS

Comment: It is correct in a term that the correct values are there, however the solution does not solve the extra space.

Answer (score 0):

Improving on @Andreas solution, using `array_map` for concision

```
<?php

$str = '#ORGNR   "123" 1
#ACCOUNT    1010    "Kassa"
#ACCOUNT    1050    "Bank"
#IB     -1 1010        1923.15
#IB     1 1050         201.42';

$arr2 = array_map(function($line){
    return preg_split("/\s+/", $line);
}, explode("\n", $str));

var_dump($arr2);
```

will give the same correct output : https://3v4l.org/20cLd

Comment: Not sure I understand what the improvement is. If you mean because if it runs x millions of lines then it will be one micro second faster then sure... If that is really the most important then sure. I generally like my code easy to read and easy to do changes on. Lockig yourself in with an array_map vs foreach is generally a bad idea. Say you want to add associative keys some day. Then it's an easy fix with a foreach, array_map usually get very muddy.

Comment: When doing data treatment like that, I like array_map because you can chain it, unit test the callback and it doesn't mutate the original array. I've worked with my share of sloppy collaborators and variable inside the foreach ends up leaking everywhere.

Comment: As for the lack of key support, I usually `array_map(fun(k,v) {...}, array_keys(arr), arr)`

Comment: If the keys should be the same as the original array. But if the keys should be, say the first item of the array then it's a bit messier

Comment: @Andreas Challenge me :D